# My student: "As of now it is unknown, why...". I have very recently found out why. Do I tell him?

Tags: ethics, undergraduate, supervision

I'm supervising an undergrad student. STEM, if that's relevant.

Due to Corona, his contract ending and me leaving this job we haven't spoken in quite some time. He has now worked at home and has written his thesis. I am currently proof-reading his (pretty much) completed thesis which he send to me on 4 days ago.

In his thesis, and obviously last time he spoke, he didn't know why there was a bump in his results. **Neither did I.** In his thesis he writes something along the lines of "as of now it is unknown...". So far, so normal.

Two days ago I more or less coincidentally found out why. It turns out it is somewhat obvious **once you know why**. What should I do now?

I could write him a mail explaining why. But this wouldn't be *his* work. It also can't be solved. It is just a "quirk" of the method he used.

I could just say nothing: "as of now it's unknown" is perfectly acceptable, but I feel in this case it's also unnecessary. After all he COULD know why.

I thought about not saying anything and just be happy about a question I already have for the oral examn. But I am afraid it might be a little too difficult for the exam and he doesn't do too well with pressure.

---

Thank you all for your input. You helped shaping my thought process in a great deal.

I ended up writing a detailed email telling him which dots to connect and leaving the rest to figure out for himself with some pointers.

I did so for a simple reason:
His statistical analysis is wrong. Furthermore I don't understand from his thesis what he did. And after all I KNOW what he wanted to do. And I know for a fact: Somewhere something went wrong. And that I can't "let slide". Incompletion is one thing, errors another.

And in order to provide an explanation I needed to show him why his data doesn't make any sense which is easiest to explain with the underlying mechaism and so on.

I will, however, use this specific topic in the oral exam. I specifically told him to make sure he knows what's happening at this particular point and I feel this is more of a warning than he probably deserves.

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: I want to help but I don't want to do his work for him. I myself have a LOT of work that I still have to get done in my last two weeks, but this is not an issue, neither of these approaches take up a lot of time. (Ironically this right now does...) So my goal is likely to get "this over with" as smoothly as possible while being the best supervisor I can.

I am not opposed to him succeeding at all.

Comment: Why don't you want to tell him? This is how science works. He can mention the source (i.e. you) if it's not a trivial insight (trivial in the sense that he should have seen it himself, in which case it would be encompassed in the acknowledgements). I would really loathe to see someone presenting work that is not - to the best of his and his supervisors/collaborator's knowledge - most complete in its conclusions and up-to-date if this is feasible in the allocated time. If it's an issue of time to prove this is the case, he could still formulate a hypothesis.

Comment: Have told him to examine the method? That should be sufficient no?

Comment: @CaptainEmacs: I could give him proof. It just wouldn't be something he has done by himself (Reason 1). If we were in an earlier stage I would give him a series of tasks that would lead him there. This way he learns nothing. Also, and I don't know if I am taking this personally which adds another layer, I actually told him once or twice how I would like him to present his results which he just did not do. If he did as I told him he might have either found out himself OR it was much less of a "jump" to get there in the exam. This was also not the first time he disregarded a "suggestion" by me.

Comment: @SolarMike Not really. At the point in time the issue came up for the first time it didn't appear too important compared to other tasks still to complete.

Comment: Well, as you say he ignores suggestions from you, then perhaps you go ahead and ask at the oral exam.

Comment: @SolarMike I thought about that. However I don't want to be petty.
I am still unsure why he ignored it. Laziness? Forgetfullness? Didn't really listen? All of these are on the table.

Comment: Surely you have worked with that student long enough to be able to decide which of those answers "why"?

Comment: @SolarMike I have worked with him for over a year (he had a temp job prior to his thesis related work) yet I absolutely have no idea as to why. Since I am actually not a terrible judge of character that bothers me quite a bit, to be honest. I feel like he lives in his own little world. Also he still is nervous when we talk and it baffles me why. (I feel I am wandering a bit off topic right now.)

Comment: @Stefan Students that simply do not listen? Yes, that exists. There is nothing you can do about it. If you think it will not outright founder him, you can use this as a point of discussion during the exam, but if he is a nervous person, it's perhaps too much to expect this to work under pressure and it can derail him. You could suggest this to be added to the thesis with a (private communication) notice.

Comment: That last edit removes the point of the existing comments and the other answer... Shame. Op you have the right to revoke it...

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like an easy solution. You can give a couple of suggestions while stressing one as more likely to yield an answer, or even a single suggestion that "may or may not work but could be an improvement on existing work". This is valid supervisory guidance, as it does not hold the student's hand but provides a direction to be explored and you are not providing a ready answer. The fact that you already know the answer is irrelevant. If the student is unable or unwilling to do so, this is not up to you. In fact, I think is it poorer supervision if you do not point out the weakness but simply let it pass.